# Permanently and reliably set gcc include path globally

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, include, default

System: LMDE4, 64bit, gcc-8.3.0, VS Code

Target File: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/videocapture_camera.cpp

Now as the title says, this starts pissing me off. Nothing is working to fix such a simple issue. And NO I don't want to always use "-I" to tell pretty obvious things to the compiler. Here is what I've done so far.

in c_cpp_properties.json of VS Code:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include/"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

in .bashrc:

```
#C Include
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/include"
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:"/usr/include/opencv2"

#C++ Include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/include"
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:"/usr/include/c++/8/"
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:"/usr/include/opencv2"

#C/C++ Include
export CPATH="/usr/include"
```

I am pretty sure that all the .bashrc exports are already a dirty workaround and still I get the following message on compile:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62,
                 from /usr/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:55,
                 from /usr/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from ~/LearnDummy/helloworld.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Well fine... stdlib.h is unknown (Jesus!)... `find /usr -name stdlib.h` gives me

```
/usr/include/stdlib.h 
/usr/include/c++/8/stdlib.h 
/usr/include/c++/8/tr1/stdlib.h 
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib.h 
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib.h
```

In addition VS Code already knows(!) where the file is once I click on "Go to Definition" and still gcc is blind. How do I get realiably rid of this?

Comment: Can you create a very small C++ program contains `cstdlib` and try to compile it from terminal with `g++ main.cpp` without compiler flags. It looks like there is a problem with your system or OS configuration.

Comment: You could try to reinstall GCC with your package manager or check the permissions for this file and the path.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
...

$ cat main.cpp
#include <cstdlib>

int main ()
{
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/include"; g++ -c main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
   75 | #include_next <stdlib.h>
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Note that `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/include"` here has the same effect as your
identical setting in your `.bashrc`.

The error does not occur if we remove that environment setting:

```
$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=; g++ -c main.cpp; echo Done
Done
```

The effect of that environment setting, as per [the GCC Manual: 3.21 Environment Variables Affecting GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html)
is the same as:

```
$ g++ -isystem /usr/include -c main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
   75 | #include_next <stdlib.h>
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

which accordingly reproduces the error.

The `-isystem` option is documented in [the GCC Manual: 3.16 Options for Directory Search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)

The *general* solution to your problem is: *Don't run a `g++` compilation in any way
that has the effect of* `g++ ... -isystem /usr/include ...`

You *can* avoid running a `g++` command in such a way because the option
`-isystem /usr/include` is unnecessary. `/usr/include` is a default search directory
for the preprocessor. You don't need to tell it to look for system header files there -
either via environment settings, or via a VS Code configuration, or any other way.

See the preprocessor's default search order for C++:-

```
$ echo | g++ -x c++ -E -Wp,-v -
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/9
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9
 /usr/include/c++/9/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include           ### <- There it is ###
End of search list.
...
```

So your comment:

> I am pretty sure that all the .bashrc exports are already a dirty workaround

is on the money<sup>1</sup>. But what's worse, the `.bashrc` setting:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/include"
```

turns the problem into *a persistent feature of your bash profile*.

**How does the error happen?**

The difference that is made to the preprocessor's search order by `-isystem /usr/include`
can be seen here:

```
$ echo | g++ -x c++ -isystem /usr/include -E -Wp,-v -
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include           ### <- Was previously last, now is first ###
 /usr/include/c++/9
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9
 /usr/include/c++/9/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
End of search list.
...
```

As you see, `/usr/include` is detected now as a *duplicated* directory in the `<...>` search
order; the second occurrence - which was *last*, previously - is deleted and the first occurrence is
retained, coming *first* in the search order.

Now recall the diagnostic:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
   75 | #include_next <stdlib.h>
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
```

The preprocessor directive `#include_next` is not a standard directive, it is
a GCC extension, documented in [the GCC manual: 2.7 Wrapper Headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Wrapper-Headers.html#Wrapper-Headers)

Whereas `#include <stdlib.h>` means:

*Include the first file called `stdlib.h` discovered in the `<...>` search order, starting from the start*

`#include_next <stdlib.h>` means:

*Include the next file called `stdlib.h` discovered in the `<...>` search order, starting from the
directory right after that of the file being processed now.*

The only directory in the `<...>` search order that contains `stdlib.h` is `/usr/include`. So,
if `#include_next <stdlib.h>` is encountered by the preprocessor in any file in any directory `dir` in the `<...>`
search order, while `/usr/include` is *first* in the `<...>` search order, there can be no directory
later than `dir` in the `<...>` search order where `<stdlib.h>` will be found. And so the error.

`#include_next <foobar.h>` can only work if the `<...>` search order places the directory containing
`<foobar.h>` after the one that contains the file that contains the directive. As a rule of thumb,
just don't mess with the `<...>` search order.

The problem just discussed was the subject of [a regression bug-report raised against GCC 6.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70129).
As you can see there, the resolution was `WONTFIX`.

---

[1] All of your `.bashrc` exports as posted are, as you suspect, poor practice.

- It isn't necessary to tell the preprocessor about any search directories in
  its default search order. You can only make things wrong.
- Directories that will *not* be found by default *should* be specified by
  `-I dir` options specified on the commandline (typically injected via parameters
  of the build configuration), so that these non-default options are visible in build logs
  for trouble shooting. "Invisible hands" are to be avoided in build systems to the
  utmost practical extent.

Comment: But how do i fix it??